# spring boot data @query to DTO

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpql, dto

I want to assign the result of a query to a DTO object. The DTO looks like this:

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Metric {
    private int share;
    private int shareholder;

    public Metric(int share, int shareholder) {
        this.share = share;
        this.shareholder = shareholder;
    }
            
}
```

And the query looks like the following:

```java
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "shareholders", path = "shareholders")
public interface ShareholderRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Shareholder, Integer> {
    @Query(value = "SELECT new com.company.shareholders.sh.Metric(SUM(s.no_of_shares),COUNT(*)) FROM shareholders s WHERE s.attend=true")
    Metric getMetrics();
}
```

However, this didn't work, as I got the following exception:

```
Caused by:org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: no_of_shares of:com.company.shareholders.sh.Shareholder[SELECT new com.company.shareholders.sh.Metric(SUM(s.no_of_shares),COUNT(*)) FROM com.company.shareholders.sh.Shareholder s WHERE s.attend=true]
```

Comment: whats the exception?

Comment: @MaciejKowalski This's is the exception raised. `Caused by:org.hibernate.QueryException:
could not
resolve property:
no_of_shares of:com.company.shareholders.sh.Shareholder[SELECT new com.company.shareholders.sh.Metric(SUM(s.no_of_shares),COUNT(*)) FROM com.company.shareholders.sh.Shareholder s WHERE s.attend=true]
`

Comment: It seems your query is a native query (!= JPQL or HQL). In that case, specify it in the annotation like : `@Query(value = "sql string ", nativeQuery = true)`

Comment: This [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64776376/8405418) could work properly for this scenario.

Answer (score 11):

In my project I've used **projections** to this like shown below:

```java
@Repository
public interface PeopleRepository extends JpaRepository<People, Long> {
    
    @Query(value = "SELECT p.name AS name, COUNT(dp.people_id) AS count " +
                   "FROM people p INNER JOIN dream_people dp " +
                   "ON p.id = dp.people_id " +
                   "WHERE p.user_id = :userId " +
                   "GROUP BY dp.people_id " +
                   "ORDER BY p.name", nativeQuery = true)
    List<PeopleDTO> findByPeopleAndCountByUserId(@Param("userId") Long userId);
    
    @Query(value = "SELECT p.name AS name, COUNT(dp.people_id) AS count " +
                   "FROM people p INNER JOIN dream_people dp " +
                   "ON p.id = dp.people_id " +
                   "WHERE p.user_id = :userId " +
                   "GROUP BY dp.people_id " +
                   "ORDER BY p.name", nativeQuery = true)
    Page<PeopleDTO> findByPeopleAndCountByUserId(@Param("userId") Long userId, Pageable pageable);
    
    }
```

The interface to which the result is projected:

```java
public interface PeopleDTO {    
    String getName();
    Long getCount();    
}
```

The fields from the projected interface must match the fields in this entity. Otherwise field mapping might break.

Also if you use `SELECT table.column` notation always define aliases matching names from entity as shown in example.

In your case change `@Query` like shown below:

```java
@Query(value = "SELECT new " + 
               "SUM(s.no_of_shares) AS sum,COUNT(*) AS count FROM " +
               "shareholders s WHERE s.attend=true", nativeQuery = true)
MetricDTO getMetrics();
```

And create `interface` `MetricDTO`  like shown below:

```java
public interface MetricDTO {
    Integer getSum();    
    Long getCount();    
}
```

Also make sure the return type of `getSum()` and `getCount()` is correct this may vary based not database.

Answer (score 4):

First, you can have a look at the Spring Data JPA documentation, you can find some help at this section : [Class-based Projections (DTOs)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/reference/repositories/projections.html#projections.dtos).

There is also a paragraph titled *Avoid boilerplate code for projection DTOs*, where they advise you to use Lombok's [`@Value`](https://projectlombok.org/features/Value) annotation, to produce an **immutable DTO**. This is similar to Lombok's [`@Data`](https://projectlombok.org/features/Data) annotation, but immutable.

If you apply it to your example, the source will look like :

```
@Value
public class MetricDto {

    private int share;
    private int shareholder;

}
```

Then, as your query is a NativeQuery, specifiy it in your Spring Data Repository.
You can find help in the documentation : [Native Queries](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#_native_queries).
You will need something like :

```
@Query(value = "SELECT new 
   com.company.shareholders.sh.MetricDto(SUM(s.no_of_shares),COUNT(*)) FROM 
   shareholders s WHERE s.attend=true", nativeQuery = true)
   MetricDto getMetrics();
```

Comment: I tried with native query but didn't work, only with HQL, but your suggestion help me

Comment: This query must not be native. We cannot use  new 
   com.company.shareholders.sh.MetricDto(...) part when using nativeQuery

Answer (score 0):

```
Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
              .createNativeQuery(stringQuery).unwrap(org.hibernate.query.Query.class);

((NativeQueryImpl) query).setResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(DtoClass.class));
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts. That's especially important when there's already an answer that's been validated by the community. Under what conditions might your approach be preferred? Are you taking advantage of new capabilities?

Answer (score 0):

You are writing a mixed query of native and jpql; `no_of_shares` is your column name in the database, but jpa is expecting you to provide not native syntax so try to replace `no_of_shares` with the corresponding field in your entity class. Or just add `nativeQuery = true` to make jpa understand it's a native query.