# hibernate native query transformer columns to complex property in dto

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-native-query

I have a native query, and I want to transformer columns (`b_id`, `b_code`, `b_desc`) to `complexProperty` (a custom object) in `ResultDto`.

**SQL**

```
select a.id   as id,
       a.name as name,
       b.id   as b_id,
       b.code as b_code,
       b.desc as b_desc
  from a
  left join b
    on a.id = b.a_id;
```

**ResultDto.class**

```
public class ResultDto {

    private String id;

    private String name;

    private ComplexPropertyDto complexProperty;

    // other fields and getter|setter

}
```

**ComplexPropertyDto.class**

```
public class ComplexPropertyDto {

    private String id;

    private String code;

    private String desc;

    // other fields and getter|setter

}
```

I try use column alias like `complexProperty.code` and use `addScalar("complexProperty.code", StringType.INSTANCE)` transformer. But I got `org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not resolve PropertyAccess for complexProperty.code on class xxx.ResultDto`.

**Update**

How to transformer columns in table `b` to property `complexProperty` in `ResultDto.class`(work as annotation `Embedded`).

Comment: You can not use `addScalar` in this way. You can create constructor for `ResultDto` and then map results via `@SqlResultSetMapping` annotation. See for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64776376/6277104)

Comment: I read your example, but my sql is dynamic. So do you have other options?

Comment: Maybe you can try to use `ResultTransformer` as it explained [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#sql-dto-query). What exactly part of your query can be dynamically changed? Is result set the same for all possible combination?

Comment: The other fields is referenced to dynamic columns(like size, color...). I tried `setResultTransformer( Transformers.aliasToBean( ResultDto.class ) )`, and get  `org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException` due to `addScalar(xxx)`.

Comment: I read the source code of `AliasToBeanResultTransformer` and wrote a custom implementation based on his method.

Comment: @xmcx did you find any solution? I am facing similar issue: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vmAq1BzMfLVRW5enPrjoxo/1

Comment: @SilverSky Try this.`Query nativeQuery = entityManager.createNativeQuery(sql); nativeQuery.unwrap(NativeQuery.class).addScalar("fieldName", fieldType).setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Bean.class))`. See [NativeQuery.addScalar​(String columnAlias, Type type)](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/query/NativeQuery.html)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you can make your particular example work, but I think this is a perfect use case for [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage). Blaze-Persistence Core is the basis which adds support for many advanced SQL concepts in the realm of the JPA model.

I created the library to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface or abstract class defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure(domain model) the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model.

A DTO model for your use case could look like the following with Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views:

```
@EntityView(TableAEntity.class)
public interface ResultDto {
    @IdMapping
    Long getId();
    String getName();
    ComplexPropertyDto getComplexProperty();

    @EntityView(TableBEntity.class)
    interface ComplexPropertyDto {
        @IdMapping
        Long getId();
        String getCode();
        String getDesc();
    }
}
```

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`ResultDto a = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, ResultDto.class, id);`

The Spring Data integration allows you to use it almost like Spring Data Projections: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-features

Comment: What should I do if `*Dto.class` does not has field `id` (or similar field)?

Comment: You just remove it. You don't require the id field, but if you have it, it's good to map it to be able to use all fetch strategies. You will get startup errors when you use an unsupported configuration though, so there is not much you can do wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it helps somebody. In my case "Could not resolve PropertyAcces" was because for set without get.