# Map Query result to dto

Tags: java, spring-boot, dto

I have these 3 independent table i.e Student, Teacher and Subject. Independent here refers that there is no relation in these tables.

I want the count of all these tables . SQL query looks like -

```
SELECT
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Student as ST, 
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Teacher as TE,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Subject as SU
```

Now I want to map this result into dto .
The DTO looks like

```
public class CountDto{
        Integer student;
        Integer teacher;
        Integer subject;
        }
```

The repository call looks like -

```
@Query(value = "SELECT\r\n"
        + "  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Student) as ST, \r\n"
        + "  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Teacher) as TE,\r\n"
        + "  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Subject) as SU", nativeQuery = true)
public CountDto getCount();
```

While calling this function I get following error stating

```
"message": "Failed to convert from type [java.lang.Object[]] to type [com.rbl.mdm.dto.CountDto ] for value '{16, 16 , 34}'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.Integer] to type [com.rbl.mdm.dto.CountDto]"
```

How should I convert my response to desired DTO ?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64776376/6277104) will be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You can declare `CountDto` as a public interface and it should work. It's called a [Projection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections) in terms of `Spring`. Or you can use [SqlResultSetMapping](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/SqlResultSetMapping.html) or [ConstructorResult](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/ConstructorResult.html) along with your class.

you don't have to implement it by any entity class, just create it like an independent interface even within the repository file:

```
public interface StudentRepository extends CrudRepository<Student, Long> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT\r\n"
            + "  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Student) as ST, \r\n"
            + "  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Teacher) as TE,\r\n"
            + "  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Subject) as SU", nativeQuery = true)
    Counts getCount();
    
    public static interface Counts {
        Integer getST();        
        Integer getTE();
        Integer getSU();
    }

}
```

Comment: As the repo call returns data from 3 independent tables, which type of Projection shall I make. As per my understanding to the Projections, they reflects methods of a entity and here we have 3 different entities !

Answer (score -1):

So here is the answer to do -
The DTO will look like

```
public CountDto{
    private Integer studentTotal;
    private Integer teacherTota;
    private Integer subjectTotal;
}
```

The repository call -

```
@Query(value = "SELECT\r\n"
        + "  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Student) as ST, \r\n"
        + "  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Teacher) as TE,\r\n"
        + "  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Subject) as SU", nativeQuery = true)
public Map<String,Integer> getCount();
```

Finally the serviceImpl--

```
public CountDto getCount{
        CountDto CountValue = new CountDto();
        Map<String,Integer> map =  repository.getCount();
        for (Map.Entry<String,Integer> entry : map.entrySet())   {
            if(entry.getKey().equals("ST"))
                CountValue.setStudentTotal( entry.getValue());
            if(entry.getKey().equals("TE"))
                CountValue.setTeacherTotal( entry.getValue());
            if(entry.getKey().equals("SU"))
                CountValue.setSubjectTotal( entry.getValue());
        }
        return CountValue ;
}
```

But the solution seems quite complex to me. Any simpler approach required.

Answer (score -1):

In pure Hibernate/JPA usage this is a simple dynamic-instantiation query (what JPA calls a "constructor result"):

```
select new CountDTO( 
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Student) as ST,
   ...
)
```

No idea here about Spring, though a word of warning.. in trying to be useful, it often "gets in the way".  Not sure that is the case here... Have you tried straight Hibernate/JPA?

Comment: If you are simply wanting to use the Spring APIs, you should remove the 'hibernate` tag.  If just using Spring there is nothing Hibernate related here.

Comment: This approach only works for non-native (JPQL) queries while OP uses native.

Comment: No idea what `@Query` is.  Its a Spring annotation apparently :shrug:  For native queries, even easier... `@NamedNativeQuery` with a result mapping using a `@ConstructorResult` result

Comment: And if the user is wanting Spring specific features only, then `hibernate` should be removed as a tag