# When I use entitymanager. Createnativequery()，Is there a simple way to put query results into a dto or vo

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

When I use entitymanager. Createnativequery()

Is there a simple way to put query results into dto
The solution I found on the Internet is

```
     List<PostVO> res = (List<PostVO>) en.createNativeQuery(s,PostVO.class).unwrap( org.hibernate.query.NativeQuery.class )
                .setResultTransformer( Transformers.aliasToBean( PostVO.class ) );
```

But it seems to have been abandoned

```
        var s = """
 SELECT     t.id,t.title,t.user_id,t.comments,t.view,t.collects,t.top,
          t.essence,t.create_time , t.modify_time ,u.username,u.alias,u.avatar
          FROM bms_post t LEFT JOIN ums_user u ON t.user_id = u.id""";
        if(tab.equals("hot")){
          s+=  """
                  date(t.create_time) <= date_add(curdate(), interval 1 day)
                  and date(t.create_time) >= date_sub(curdate(), interval 7 day)
                  order by t.view desc, t.create_time desc
                    """.indent(1);
        }else s+="order by t.create_time desc".indent(1);
      var res =  en.createNativeQuery(s).getResultList();
```

dto code

```
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
//@AllArgsConstructor
public class PostVO implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -261082150965211545L;
    private String id;
    private String userId;
    private String title;
    private Integer comments;
    private Boolean top;
    private Boolean essence;
    private Integer collects;
    private List<BmsTag> tags;
    private Integer view;
    private Date createTime;
    private Date modifyTime;
    private String avatar;
    private String alias;
    private String username;
}
```

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64762080/how-to-map-sql-native-query-result-into-dto-in-spring-jpa-repository/64776376) will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. What you need to do is

1/ Have constructor with parameters

2/ Modify your query to something like

```
"SELECT new " + PostVO.class.getName() + "(t.id,t.title,t.user_id,t.comments,t.view,t.collects,t.top, t.essence,t.create_time , t.modify_time ,u.username,u.alias,u.avatar ) <your FROM query here> "
```

**Edit**: using `getSimpleName()` make it incorrect because it cannot locate the class, using `getName()` solves the problem.

And use `createQuery` for this case

```
TypedQuery<PostVO> typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(<your sql>, PostVO.class);
typedQuery.setParameter("id", id); // or whatever paramerters of yours
return typedQuery.getSingleResult(); // or get a list, based on your needs
```

Comment: why have trouble? ,help check my  code      ```        var a="SELECT new " + PostVO.class.getSimpleName() + "(t.id,t.user_id ,t.title) from bms_post t";
        var  res =  en.createNativeQuery(a).getResultList();
        System.out.println(res);```

Comment: sorry my mistake, it should be `getName()` instead of `getSimpleName()`. You will get the path of your class for example `com.yourbusiness.dto.PostVO`