# Is there a way to use a custom, arbitrary SQL query for loading an entity in Jmix?

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, jpa, jmix

I am using Jmix 1.3.1.

I have a database structure (that I cannot change) that is as follows:

- There is a large table with several columns, which I'll call table T.
- One of these columns (string-valued), which I'll call column L, is the only one I am interested in. It has a few distinct values.

I want to build an entity picker where the user can select one of the values from column L for filtering a report by that column. I do not want the entire table T displayed in the entity picker, only the distinct values of column L.

My initial attempt was to create a @JmixEntity annotated class with only my column L in it with a @NamedNativeQuery annotation and a @SqlResultSetMapping annotation that contained an SQL query like `SELECT DISTINCT L FROM T`, similar to what I found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64776376/14939397). I have no idea whether this is even supposed to work with Jmix, I can only find information about this approach with JPA, not with Jmix.

My current attempt is to have two classes:

- One annotated with @JmixEntity, @Table, @Entity and @Store like any other class for the entire table T, but with the only fields being the ID and the column L.
- One annotated only with @JmixEntity with only the column L which also serves as @InstanceName and @Id.

Then I adapt the standard entity browser for the first one of these classes to have a query `select distinct e.L FROM T e`.

Both of these approaches are causing the entity picker to open, but no data to be displayed, and I am stuck on how to debug what is going on. I am not sure which of these approaches might even work or whether there might be another approach to achieve what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this problem by not connecting the entity to the database at all (i.e. no @Table, no @Store, no @NamedNativeQuery annotation, no annotations other than @JmixEntity and @Entity).

Then in my UI controller, in a method like the one knstvk suggested for debugging purposes, I created a JdbcTemplate and put my query into a jdbcTemplate.queryForList call. Then I could manually dataManager.create the needed entities.

I am not claiming that this is an especially elegant solution, but it is working.

Answer (score 0):

The first approach should work. To debug what is loaded, create a load delegate in your list view and you will be able to put a breakpoint in your code:

```
@Autowired
private DataManager dataManager;

@Install(to = "usersDl", target = Target.DATA_LOADER)
private List<User> usersDlLoadDelegate(final LoadContext<User> loadContext) {
    List<User> users = dataManager.loadList(loadContext);
    return users;
}
```