# How to fetch data from multiple tables and put into an custom object? spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, jpql, freemarker

**JpaRepository**

```
public interface SessionsStoreRepository extends JpaRepository<SessionsStore, Integer> {

SessionsStore findBySessionId(String sessionId);

//JPQL
@Query(value = "SELECT s.username,s.loginTime,s.logoutTime, e.firstName, e.lastName from SessionsStore s, Employee e "
        + " where e.username = s.username and s.isActive= 1")
List<ActiveSession> findUsers();           
}
```

**ActiveSession**

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class ActiveSession {

    private String username;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private LocalDateTime loginTime;
    private LocalDateTime logoutTime;
}
```

How can I store the data fetch by @Query(...) in ActiveSession Object Or is there any other way? I tried storing data into object (i.e List<Object>) but I'm using ftl for view and it does not allow you fetch the data unless the object have getters.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a class-based projection to achive this.

More information [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-projections), or there is a good example of how to use it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53322203/spring-boot-data-query-to-dto)